# How do I search for integer (x,y) in a textfile using python?

Tags: python, search, matrix, keyword

I have a matrix stored in a textfile as:

```
(i, j)      count
```

I need to search for the pair (i,j). How do I do that?

```
with open("matrix.txt","r") as searchmat:            
        for line in searchmat:
                word=str((x,y))
                if word in line:
            t=line.split('\t')
            f=t[1]
                return f
```

I am getting **NONE** for all the values.

Comment: You are getting NONE for *all* the values? What *values* are you talking about? There is only *one* value returned.

Comment: I am getting none for all values of "x" and "y"

Comment: @Shawn: I believe the indentation is the problem here, so I've rolled this back.

Comment: @Chinmay that's definitely a possibility. Well spotted!

Comment: As an aside, are you repeating that for every (x,y) pair you're interested in? If you have many pairs to look up, and if the textfile is not prohibitively large, I would suggest parsing the data and storing it in a dict. Searching in a dict would then be quick and simple.

Comment: `word=str((x,y))` Is this an error in posting with no quotes around or are you converting a Tuple into a string for laughs? (It does convert it to the exact string representation you have there)

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine (assuming you got your indentations right). Maybe there is an issue with your data file format. More than one tab character in the separator perhaps? Try using `t=line.split()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have messed up indentation. From looking at the code you've (I assume) pasted here, it looks like you have mixed tabs and spaces, which Python most definitely does not like. Replace all tabs in your file with spaces, and indent your code so it looks like this:

```
with open("matrix.txt","r") as searchmat:            
    for line in searchmat:
        word=str((x,y))
        if word in line:
            t=line.split('\t')
            f=t[1]
            return f
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
def reader(path):
    import re
    pattern = re.compile("^\((\d*), (\d*)\).*$")
    with open(path) as searchmat:
        for line in searchmat:
            print re.match(pattern, line).group(1, 2)   # print both raw groups
            print int(re.match(pattern, line).group(1)) # first number as int
            print int(re.match(pattern, line).group(2)) # second number as int
```

It traverses the file given by `path` and looks in each line for the pattern you described.